# select each item it should show cross symbol and clicking that symbol should delete the item

Tags: javascript, html, angular

- by using the below close button code I am trying delete each item from drop down in my angular code.
  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_close_list_items.asp
- so I reused the code but its not working.
- when I select each item it should show cross symbol and clicking that symbol should delete the item.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my stackblitz below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-hvk4p8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {

    var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
      closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: While you've posted links to your code, we do require that the relevant "*[mcve]*" is here in your problem. This is in order to guard against link-rot and to ensure that the solution to your problem is relevant to your problem, and also to ensure that the relevant code is available for future users (and any answers can be directly relevant to that example code).

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or css. Please only tag what is relevant to the actual problem

Comment: @all can you let me know how to do it...I will try it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I give this answer, I have to recommend that you do a tutorial on Angular2 since it is obvious that you are trying to mix and match things that shouldn't be used together. The official Angular website has a good tutorial.

No need to try document.getElementsByClassName; The way I would do it is by taking advantage of ngFor and Angulars "Event binding" rather than searching through the DOM

in the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  items = ["volvo","saab","mercedes","audi"];
  currentItem;
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  updateCurrent(selected){
    this.currentItem = selected;
    console.log(this.currentItem);
  }

  delete(itemSel: any){
    console.log(itemSel);
    var index = this.items.indexOf(itemSel);
    //if (index>-1)
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(this.items)
  }
}
```

in the template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<select (change)="updateCurrent($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
<div class="close" (click)="delete(currentItem)">X</div>
```